# what is the difference between element and sequence for minoccurs and maxoccurs in xsd

Tags: xsd

I am new to XSD, could you please help me for the following question:

**What is the difference between element and sequence for minoccurs and maxoccurs in xsd.**

thanks in advance.

Prasad J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### w3schools

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/)

#### sequence

- maxOccurs    Optional. Specifies the maximum number of times the sequence element can occur in the parent element. The value can be any number >= 0, or if you want to set no limit on the maximum number, use the value "unbounded". Default value is 1
- minOccurs    Optional. Specifies the minimum number of times the sequence element can occur in the parent element. The value can be any number >= 0. Default value is 1

#### element

- maxOccurs    Optional. Specifies the maximum number of times this element can occur in the parent element. The value can be any number >= 0, or if you want to set no limit on the maximum number, use the value "unbounded". Default value is 1. This attribute cannot be used if the parent element is the schema element
- minOccurs    Optional. Specifies the minimum number of times this element can occur in the parent element. The value can be any number >= 0. Default value is 1. This attribute cannot be used if the parent element is the schema element